# Why does Sourceforge not have the 4.6.5 files?

Tags: drupal

Sourceforge shows the latest release 4.6.5 for Drupal 7 but the files are 'not found' if you try to download them.  Also Sourceforge shows the headline latest release to be 4.6.4.  What's going on?

Comment: I replicate: http://sourceforge.net/projects/civicrm/files/civicrm-stable/4.6.5/ "The "/civicrm-stable/4.6...-4.6.5-drupal.tar.gz" file could not be found or is not available. Please select another file."

Answer (score 2):

Sourceforge had a major failure on 7/16 and their services have been [slowly coming back online](http://sourceforge.net/blog/sourceforge-infrastructure-and-service-restoration-update-for-724/). Expect to see CiviCRM downloads working normally again soon.

In the meantime you can get the latest version directly from http://civicrm.org/download

Comment: except for the localisation files...

Comment: @Coleman As of 7/30 4.6.5 files are still unavailable on sourceforge.